# File storage for Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, storage, docker-swarm

I've been looking for weeks now for a suitable solution for persistent distributed file storage for my Docker Swarm implementation to no avail.

I've have three nodes in a swarm, which multiple instances of multiple applications running perfectly fine.

I'm at the point now where I need some consistency in storage across each of my applications but I don't seem to be able to find any straight forward solution to the problem.

I want to take the least configurable approach as possible.

I have a single cluster, with three nodes, and let's just say an instance of an application running on each.

What is the best option here:
1. I have something to replicate files across each of my nodes
2. I have something to replicate files across each of my containers
3. I use a separate file store that I connect my nodes to
4. I use a separate file store that I connect my containers to

Either way, I need some form of replication at a minimum for redundancy.

Appreciate if anyone can set me on the right course with some options!

Comment: GlusterFS. But any distributed file system would do.

Answer (score 4):

Well `performance/storage space` wise, replicating is not the answer, You need a solution with `shared storage`. Like what we use in `Server Virtualization`. There are many SAN Storage brands out there, if you got the cash.

Now if you have a `virtualization infrastructure` in place like me (`vmware vsphere` in my case) you can use available `SAN Datastores` to store volumes via [docker-volume vsphere driver](https://github.com/vmware/docker-volume-vsphere). You will create docker volumes on `vmware datastores`, and they are shared between your `docker swarm` so in case of failure docker will start the containers (with their persistent data on volume) on another node in the swarm.

There are similar `drivers` for other vendors (Virtualization/Storage) too.

There are Cloud based solutions, you can use `Ceph`, `glusterfs`, `flocker` or other opensource distributed file systems for storing your containers `persistent data`.

Answer (score 1):

*Docker's* road map is to implement distributed volume drivers and the most promising one is from *infinity*. They will support distribution across all swarm nodes and from what I have seen the design promises very good performance.

This will probably take at least another 6 months to mature and until than you need to use some shared storage attached to all nodes.
(the easiest one being *NFS*)

So the idea is to mount a shared folder on all nodes and use the

```
docker run -v /nfsShare:/container/folder
```

if you run a container, or if you deploy a service

```
docker service create -mount type=bind,src=/nfsShare,dst=/container/folder
```

if the docker host is running on alpine you can use an image I created to automate the process.

Here is a link that explains how to use it:
https://www.vip-consult.solutions/post/persistent-storage-docker-swarm-nfs#content